# Proving difference quotient is equal to derivative at 0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

everyone, thankfully I was able to figure out parts 1 and parts 3.  However, I am stuck on part 2. The conditions somewhat confuse me.  All I so far was (first steps are similar to part 1):

Start with:

$f(a_n)=f(0)+a_n(f'(0)+c_n  $

$f(b_n)=f(0)+b_n(f'(0))+d_n   $

such that $|c_n/a_n| $ goes to 0 and $|dn/bn| $ goes to 0.

From there I get plugging in for $f(b_n)$ and $f(a_n)$:

$D_n=f'(0)+(d_n-c_n)/(b_n-a_n)  $

So now I somehow need to show that:
$\lim (d_n-c_n)/(b_n-a_n)=0     $ to show that $D_n=f'(0)$, using the conditions $0<a_n<b_n$ and $b_n/(b_n-a_n)$.  The problem is I'm not sure how to use these conditions to show that the limit goes to 0.  For part 1, it was pretty simple using Squeeze Theorem.  However, I can't figure out how to do it now with these new conditions.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Use the fact that $c_{n} /a_{n} \to 0,d_{n}/b_{n}\to 0,a_{n}<b_{n}$. Note that $|d_{n} - c_{n} |\leq |d_n|+|c_n|$ and divide multiply by $b_{n} $.

Comment: Makes sense how do I the bn/(bn-an) part though?

Comment: Consider $\frac {d_n}{b_n-a_n}$ and $\frac {c_n}{b_n-a_n}$ separetely. For the latter you need to know that $\frac {a_n}{b_n-a_n}$ is also bounded. This is easy from the fact that $\frac {b_n}{b_n-a_n}$ is bounded.

Comment: I''ll try it out now.  Can I verify with you if it is correct?  Thanks.

Comment: I am here to help.

Comment: Ok, so I am slightly confused: I have: 0<= (dn/bn-an).  I need to show dn/bn-an is less than dn/bn.  However the condition I'm given is that 0<an<bn.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$0\leq\left|\frac{d_n-c_n} {b_n-a_n} \right|\leq\frac{|d_n|+|c_n|} {b_n-a_n} =\left(\frac{|d_n|} {b_n} +\frac{|c_n|} {b_n} \right) \frac{b_n} {b_n-a_n} \leq \left(\frac{|d_n|} {b_n} +\frac{|c_n|} {a_n} \right) M$$ and now the last expression tends to $(0+0)M=0$ so that by squeeze theorem $|d_{n} - c_n|/(b_n-a_n) \to 0$ and your job is done.